# What is a good design pattern for awaiting Promise.all with extra data

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I would like some guidance on a good way to pass data along with an array of promises so that the data can be used later after calling `await Promise.all()`.

I'm pretty new to node and `promises`. The code below, in summary, does what I want, but it seems messy to have the `promises array` separate from the corresponding `data array`. I would think this is a common occurrence and would have a simpler solution.
I was able to accomplish the same result by attaching a `then()` function to the `asyncFunc return`, but this makes the code messier and for some reason takes twice as long to execute.

```
async function foo(inputs) {
 var promises = [];
 var datas = [];
 for (var input of inputs.values()) {
  promises.push(asyncFunc(input.a));
  datas.push(input.b);
 }
 var outputs = [];
 for (let result of (await Promise.all(promises)).values()) {
  outputs.push({
   data: datas.shift(),
   result: result
  });
 }
 return outputs;
}
```

Comment: `(await Promise.all(promises)).map((result, i) => ({ data: datas[i], result })`

Answer (score 0):

You will often face this kind of problem in nodeJs, the answer is how you want your async function react.

1. If you want it run sequentially, you don't need promise all. The code will look like this.

```js
async function foo(inputs) {
 const results = [];
 const datas = [];
 for (const input of inputs.values()) {
  const result = await asyncFunc(input.a);
  results.push(result);
  datas.push(input.b);

 }
 const outputs = [];
 for (const result of results) {
  outputs.push({
   data: datas.shift(),
   result: result
  });
 }
 return outputs;
}
```

2. In case you have to use the promise all, you can use another variable to hold the values, this will make the code less messy.

```js
 const results = await Promise.all(promises)).values();
 for (const result of results) {
  outputs.push({
   data: datas.shift(),
   result: result
  });
 }
```